# Which is the best way to do an infinite scroll?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, infinite

I must do an infinite scroll, but which is the best way?

- Load all items once (only one request to database), store them in an array for (example a javascript array), then splice the array when reach the bottom page;
- Load items with limit/offset (multiple requests to database).

And why one is prefer to the other?

Comment: Depends on what your outcome is. If you want it to be fast for the user, I'd to multiple request. This also helps in case people don't keep scrolling. It also depends on how many items you, if you have 1000s, you don't want load them all at once. Multiple request to the server isn't that much more of a load to the server / client as it is to load all at once.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the situation, but in most of the cases, the second approach is recommended for big data (the same approach they use for facebook), because you don't need to do a huge transaction. sometimes you won't need all those data at once.